# Problems with tkinter textbox output into a .txt file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.5

I'm trying to create a program that opens a tkinter window with 4 entries. When I press a button, it's supposed to write everything from the entries into a .txt file from top to bottom. I've managed to make it work like I wanted to, but my only problem is that it only writes the last line into the created .txt file instead of all four. I am still kind of new to working with tkinter and dont really know how to fix this.

This is my code so far:

```
import os

from tkinter import *
fields = "Vorname", "Nachname", "Beruf", "Wohnort"

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      textfile = open("test2.txt", "w")
      textfile.write('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == "__main__":
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind("<Return>", (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   b1 = Button(root, text="Drucken",
          command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text="Abbrechen", command=root.destroy)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're opening the file to write every time through the loop. Don't do that. Also, use a `with` block. So you should have `with open('file', 'w')  as textfile: for entry in entries: ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are opening the file at each iteration of the loop and the info is being overwritten.

You have two options:

- Use `with` to open the file in `fetch` which closes the file on exit of block:

  ```
  def fetch(entries):
      with open("test2.txt", "w") as textfile:
          for entry in entries:
              field = entry[0]
              text  = entry[1].get()
              textfile.write('%s: "%s"\n' % (field, text))
  ```
- Use `close` or `flush` to write to the file in `fetch`:

  ```
  def fetch(entries):
      textfile = open("test2.txt", "w")
      for entry in entries:
          field = entry[0]
          text  = entry[1].get()
          textfile.write('%s: "%s"\n' % (field, text))
      textfile.close()
  ```

There is a third option which involves saving the pointer to the location in the file which you ended write at and restart at that point but that would overcomplicate it since it can easily be solved with a simpler method.

Comment: You're wrong about the reason - it has nothing to do with not closing the file/flushing the bufffer, and everything to do with the fact that the OP is opening the file *4 times*, and simply writing over what's been written.

Comment: Not a reason to downvote, but FWIW the *only* reason that you should not use a `with` block for your file operations is if you're passing a file throughout you program (or you need one to hang around forever).

Comment: ah ok! my bad then haha the solution is correct but for different reason hahaha i'll edit start text then

Comment: Is that better? also added the fact that he could save a reference to last written location but said it wuld make it more complicated

Comment: Much. Not sure if worrying about pointers and file locations is worthwhile at all, because when you open a file in 'w' mode it actually truncates the file, so...

Comment: Note that even with this improved version "test2.txt" will get over-written each time `fetch` is called. This may (or may not) be the desired behaviour. If it's not desired, you can open the file in "a" mode.

Comment: hadn't even thought of that! many store a global id to save different test{i}.txt during execution?

Comment: Well i tried the first option and it worked out fine! now i just need to find out how to make it so they are written under eachother.

Comment: @Mixone like with an "enter" after every textbox line that it writes into the .txt file

Comment: if you look at the code i wrote, in the string part there is an "\n" at the end, that is the newline character, if you used the code it should be happening already if not you can add yet another one just in case

Comment: @Mixone Thanks for mentioning it again. I forgot to add that because i didnt notice the difference at first. One more thing though. Is there a way i can make an extra button which writes the text from the .txt file back into the entry after closing and restarting the program? I already have a button written into my current code.